# Strategy for Coin Toss Team Game with Elimination

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

Consider a game with N groups of people, where each group has 8 people.
Each round, every person in every group chooses H or T. A leader flips a fair coin. If a person guessed incorrectly, they are out of the game.
Repeat rounds until there is one single winner standing. Their group wins.

1. What is the probability that any one group will win?
2. Is it better for a group to evenly split their guesses (for example, 4 people guess H and 4 people guess T), or to go all-in on one guess for a round?
3. What are some strategies for a group to increase their probability that they will win?

Note: this is a real world game I've played, not a problem for school or out of a textbook, I'm a few years out of school now and pretty rusty at probabilities.

Edit: I'm also interested in a general case where *up to* 8 players could be on a team.

Comment: Note - here are my current attempts/understanding at the problem:

The probability of guessing a coin flip is 1/2.

The probability of a single person guessing N rounds correctly in a row is Pguess(N) = (1/2)^N.

The probability of someone in a group guessing N rounds correctly in a row is Ptable(N) = 8 * Pguess(N) = 8 * (1/2)^N.

Which leads me to, how do I know how many rounds there will be? that's where I'm stuck. With only 1 team, there could be as little as 3 rounds to reach down to 1 person, but there could be infinite rounds if everyone guesses correctly. Is it a distribution?